# Y wire question: Help to connect smart thermostat with C wire adaptor

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

Trying to install an amazon smart thermostat with a c wire adaptor.

On the thermostat end, pretty straight forward. Rh, W, Y, G wires. Noted that a blue colored wire is Y wire. SEE PICTURE

When I went to the control board inside the hvac, noted that the blue wire is not connected to anything. It is just hanging free… Instead, there are two separate Y wires not going to thermostat. One of the Y wires lead to exterior AC. I am not sure where the second Y wire leads to. It disappears in the ceiling. Unfortunately, we have foam insulation. So, what is the real Y wire that should go into connector?

---

Thermostat controls ac and gas furnace

PICTURE SHOWING CONTROL BOARD IN HVAC
As you can see, the thermostat wire (dark brown)connects to R, W, G but the blue wire is hanging free.

The light brown wire connects C and Y goes to exterior AC unit

I am not sure the role of the stand-alone white Y wire.

[image]

---

[image]

Thermostat wiring picture

First picture from hvac unit

Comment: Please add to your question, tell us what kind of system you have. Heating, cooling, air, water, heat pump?  A picture of the control board would help, well lit and in focus so the colors of the thermostat wires are clear where they are connected to anything.  If the cable from the thermostat does not go directly to the control board, you need to find any splices and document them carefully for the question.

Comment: There's probably a splice in the furnace. What's going on there?

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers). Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Aye -- can you find the splice and get us photos of it?

Comment: The blue wire is used as Y in the thermostat, so in theory it should be connected to the Y terminal in the furnace to control "call for cool".   But it's not connected and instead there is a second mystery white wire connected to the Y terminal.  We need to know what that is!   The OTHER white wire, the light brown cable, is fine, ignore that for now.  Would it be easy to replace the dark brown cable entirely from the thermostat to the furnace?  You need 5 wires, not 4.